# Migrating items between ArcGIS Online accounts

Tags: arcgis-online

How do I move applications/items between ArcGIS Online accounts?

I was trying to use ArcGIS Online Assistant, which uses the ArcGIS REST API to provide items migration, but it will break the links and content becomes lost by using this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try sharing the items to the public (Everyone) and then downloading them from the other account.

I have done that a few times and it has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to your content and clicking "Add Item" then 'on the web' category, input your URL to your item, and it should add.